# How to install TinyDB?

Tags: python, tinydb

I am trying to install TinyDB as I need to use it for a python program. I have tried following tutorials that suggest installing it via the command prompt. However, whenever I type 'python', it says ''python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.' I have tried adding 'C:\python37-32\' to the end of the PATH variable but it has made no difference. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: When you run the python installer, one of the options is whether to add it to the system `PATH` environment variable. It sounds like you didn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that `python.exe` is actually in `C:\python37-32\`
2. Check if `PATH` is set correctly in your `cmd`, type `echo %PATH%`, if not, try rebooting your system

Once the directory where `python.exe` is correctly added to PATH, you should be able to run

```
 python -m pip install tinydb
```